# NPTL data structures by python

Tags: python-3.x

A list of integers is said to be a valley if it consists of a sequence of strictly decreasing values followed by a sequence of strictly increasing values. The decreasing and increasing sequences must be of length at least 2. The last value of the decreasing sequence is the first value of the increasing sequence.

Write a Python function `valley(l)` that takes a list of integers and returns True if l is a valley and False otherwise.

Here are some examples to show how your function should work.

```
valley([3,2,1,2,3])
```

> True

```
valley([3,2,1])
```

> False

```
valley([3,3,2,1,2])
```

> False

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: what kinds of questions can I ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Remember, we need Minimal, complete, Verifiable Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. When you are finished, you may click `edit` to edit your question, so that we may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def valley(list):
  if(len(list)<4):
    return False
  cond1=False
  cond2=False
  cnt=1
  for i in range(0,len(list)-1):
    if list[i]>list[i+1] and cond1==False and cond2==False:
      cond1=True
    elif list[i]>list[i+1] and cond1==True and cond2==False:
      continue
    elif list[i]<list[i+1] and cond1==False:
      return False
    elif list[i]==list[i+1]:
      return False
    elif list[i]<list[i+1] and cond1==True and cond2==False:
      cond2=True
  return cond1 and cond2
```

Comment: some explanation would help

Answer (score 0):

```
def valley(l):
    direction = []

    i = 0
    if(l[i]<l[i+1]):
        direction.append(1) # 1 means direction is upwards
    else:
        direction.append(-1) # -1 means direction is downwards

    i = i+1

    while(i<len(l)-1):
        if(direction[-1] == 1) and (l[i]>l[i+1]):
            direction.append(-1)
        elif(direction[-1] == -1) and (l[i] < l[i+1]):
            direction.append(1)
        i = i+1

    if(len(direction)==2) and (sum(direction) == 0) and (direction[0] == -1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```